# Angular TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected

Tags: javascript, angular, crud, fetch-api

I am trying to fetch a log by it's id but I am getting a TypeError.
This is my code:

```
export class LogComponent implements OnInit {

  id!: number;

  logs!: Log[];
  log!: string

  constructor(private logService: LogService) {
  }

  public show: boolean = false;
  public buttonName: any = 'Load message';

  ngOnInit() {
    this.logService.getLogs().subscribe((data: Log[]) => {
      console.log(data)
      this.logs = data

    })

  }

  showLog() {
    this.show = !this.show;
    this.logService.getLogById(this.id).subscribe((data: Log) => {
      console.log(data)
      // @ts-ignore
      this.log = data;
      if (this.show)
        this.buttonName = "Hide";
      else
        this.buttonName = "Load message";
    })
  }

  
}
```

And this is my service component :

```
getLogById(id:number): Observable<Log> {
    // @ts-ignore
    return this.http.get<Log>(`${this.API}/${id}`).pipe(catchError(this.handleError
    ));
  }

  private handleError(httpErrorResponse:HttpErrorResponse){
    if(httpErrorResponse.error instanceof ErrorEvent){
      console.error(httpErrorResponse.error.message)
    }
```

The error that I am getting is :

```
TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected.
GET http://localhost:8081/logs/undefined
```

The error is showing the Id an an undefined. any solutions ?

Comment: Where do you initilized id field in a code?

Comment: in the Log class i have ```export class Log {

  // @ts-ignore
  id: number
  // @ts-ignore
  payload: string ;


}```

Comment: You have declared not initialize id field in your component class.  So you can initialized by passing id value of log into `showLog(id: number)` from your template html. I hope it make sense. `(click)="showLog(log.id);"`

Comment: i have tried that, but it is not working. getting the same error

Answer (score 1):

My take on this is that the problem happens because you don't return anything from `catchError`.

The log ID that you are providing to your service method, is likely `undefined` as seen in your console log `GET http://localhost:8081/logs/undefined` and your backend returns an error because it cannot find the log with id `undefined` and the `catchError` triggers in this case.

You can return `null` or an empty object when your backend throws an error:

```
private handleError(httpErrorResponse:HttpErrorResponse){
  if(httpErrorResponse.error instanceof ErrorEvent){
    console.error(httpErrorResponse.error.message)
  }
  return of(null); // or return of({} as Log);
}
```

If you start to get type errors because your service method is only supposed to return an instance of `Log` (strict null checks) then you can change the type of the return value:

```
getLogById(id:number): Observable<Log | null>
```

And make sure to adjust the code that calls this method too, to account for the fact that now the returned log can be `null`.